# Design of tab in app breaks for Android on Nexus 4

Tags: android, tabs

[image]

this is the image of my app in nexus4 upper layout where you can see gree toggle one strip gets little above from screen in nexus 4 but when i run this app in motoe it runs vry good and no defects in design layout..what may be the issue with this phone?

Comment: Have you tried to search before posting here?

Comment: yes man but no help

Comment: Add your layout file where tabs, app Bar, its present

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`  to your appBar/toolbar layout.

What happens here since the layout is missing the flag it tries to draw the toolbar under statusbar ie., it doesnot care about system level insets(statusbar). So we need to add this line inside the layout which needs to be drawn below statusbar.

Edit :

You can give `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the top level layout elements when it needs to be drawn under statusbar. If something needs to be drawn below status bar use false.

Comment: thanks mate but the problem is im also using an inner tab when i switch in inner tab lower tab goes down :(

Comment: its happening in nexus only you told to do fitssystemwindows="true" upper layout wont go up now but bottom tabs move down below navigation bar

Comment: So its not the problem with mobile, but with the OS. I am still sure that the problem is to do with fitsSystemWindows tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a know issue, so, firstly, set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to your root layout, and then just add top padding that is equal to status bar height to your tooblar, if Android version >= Lollipop:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    toolbar.setPadding(toolbar.getPaddingLeft(), getStatusBarHeight(), toolbar.getPaddingRight(), toolbar.getPaddingBottom());
}

protected int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

That's it!